# Counting pulses using SMT32f407VG

Tags: timer, counter, stm32f4

I want to count the pulses generated by Picoscope, my signal frequency is (20Hz)

I used the timer2, the problem is that the counter increment to 1 and came back to 0, I don't understand why ??? since it must increment every 50ms.

[image]

I devellopped the code show bellow :

```
 #include "stm32f4xx.h"
 #include "stm32f4xx_rcc.h"
 #include "stm32f4xx_gpio.h"
 #include "stm32f4xx_tim.h"

 void GPIO_Init_TM(void);

 int variable = 0;

 int main(void)
 {
  GPIO_Init_TM();
  while(1)
  {
    variable = TIM_GetCounter(TIM2);
  }
 }

 void GPIO_Init_TM(void)

 {

RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);

RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM2, ENABLE);

GPIO_InitTypeDef gpioStructure;
//TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef timerInitStructure;

gpioStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_15 ;
gpioStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
gpioStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;

GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &gpioStructure);

GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource15, GPIO_AF_TIM2);

TIM_EncoderInterfaceConfig(TIM2, TIM_EncoderMode_TI1,TIM_ICPolarity_Rising, TIM_ICPolarity_Rising );
TIM_SetAutoreload (TIM2, 0xffff);

TIM_Cmd(TIM2, ENABLE);
```

}

and this is the result I get :

[image]

Comment: Any questions here?

Comment: The counter must increment every 50ms since the Frequency is at 50 20Hz, but it increments just to 1 and came back to 0, I don't understand why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, that you configured your TIM in encoder mode. An quatrature encoder uses two inputs with 90° phase shifted pulse signals to detect up or down counting. See the red path in the picture below.

So delete :

```
TIM_EncoderInterfaceConfig(TIM2, TIM_EncoderMode_TI1,TIM_ICPolarity_Rising, TIM_ICPolarity_Rising );
```

[image]

If you just want a single input pulse counter, you have to use the external trigger (TIMx_ETR) as timer trigger. (green path in the pic)

Add a complete timer initialization and something like:

```
TIM_SelectInputTrigger(TIM2, TIM_TS_ETRF);
```

Comment: For Timer 9 I used this function TIM_TIxExternalClockConfig(TIM9, TIM_TIxExternalCLK1Source_TI2, TIM_ICPolarity_Rising, 0x0F); and it works, the external signal is on the pin PA3 channel 2 for the TImer 9